# Amazon Athena Date Functions

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena, presto, ansi-sql

I understand Athena uses Presto, however the function last_day_of_month(x) in the  documentation doesn't seem to work in AWS Athena.

Is there a function I can use to get the last day of the previous month based on the current date (30 september 2021), last day of previous year (31 december 2021) and last day of the half year (30 June 2022) etc?

I used the below script to do this, however it would be good to know if there's a function I can use or simpler way to run the dates.

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' day
```

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('year',(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' day)) - interval '1' day
```

```sql
SELECT date_add('month',6, date_trunc('year',(date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' day)) - interval '1' day)
```

Comment: Thanks it does, and I updated my workgroup to version 3 and tested the last_day_of_month function that now works which is great

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to upgrade your Workgroup to use the Athena engine version 3, which already supports `last_day_of_month(x)` function.

Athena is based on Presto/Trino, and each version of the Athena engine is based on a different version of the open-source project. You can control the version from the Workgroups menu and even let Athena upgrade the engine automatically for you.

Second, if you want a get the last day of the previous month, the easiest way is to create the first day of the following month and substruct one day from it.

```
SELECT date '2012-08-01' - interval '1' day
```

Therefore, if you want the last day of the previous month, and as suggested in the comment, using `date_trunc`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date ) - interval '1' day

--- half year back
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '6' month) - interval '1' day

--- one year back
SELECT date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' year) - interval '1' day
```

Comment: Thankyou - very helpful re the version of the Athena engine and the workgroup. 

Is there a way to define these as variables similar to MS SQL Server or do you have to use prepared statements for that?

Comment: I would argue that `date_trunc` approach from the OP is more readable (and maybe even more performant) then the suggested one.

Comment: You are right @GuruStron. I fixed the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: @Guy I was trying to use last_day_of_month based on docs and your response was helpful as it appears my workgroup is under engine 2. But, I checked settings and it's set to "automatically upgrade". Does this mean AWS will only automatically upgrade when engine 2 is deprecated? Thank you.

Comment: @TechNewbie, AWS is not specific regarding the timing of the automatic upgrade. I don't think it is a matter of the deprecation of the version and more about the stability of the newer version. You can always set the engine version manually if you need.